# Is there a way to pass (index) which button has been pressed in a ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swift, button, foreach, swiftui

*Hello wonderful helpers!*

I am trying to load a detailView with the correct information from an Array to my MotherView when a ForEach-button is being pressed.

I don't know how to pass on which card has been pressed, to remember the index when i then try to load my DetailView with the same information. It's the last "index" there which sets me off. If i replace that with [0] it will display, all good, but just the sample data from the first item. Anyone who can help a very frustrated fresh coder?

```
    ZStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {self.showDetailView.toggle()}) {
                    ForEach(flowerData) { index in
                        FlowerCard(flower: self.flower)
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        if showDetailView {
            FlowerDetailView(flower: self.flower[index]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use button (or even onTapGesture) for every card, like (scratchy)

```
@State private var clickedCard: Int? = nil
...

ForEach(flowerData) { index in
    Button(action: {
        self.clickedCard = index // << store in member
        self.showDetailView.toggle()
    }) {
        FlowerCard(flower: self.flower)
    }
}

...
    if showDetailView && index != nil {
        FlowerDetailView(flower: self.flower[index!]
    }
```